# Infinite Scroll jQuery Plugin: how to fix loading graphic from "animating" left to center of page?

Tags: jquery, html, css, infinite-loop

I am using Paul Irish's Infinite Scroll jQuery Plugin and I notice that every time I load more content onto my page it appends the following HTML markup into the DOM as a loading graphic:

```
<div id="infscr-loading" style="display: none; width: 100%;">
    <img alt="Loading..." src="loading.gif" />
    <div></div>
</div>
```

If you watch closely as the loading graphic is plucked out of the DOM and then reinserted once new content is being loaded, the graphic actually animates from the left side of the page to the center. How do I eliminate this possibly unintended "animation" from taking place? I'm not quite sure this is actually the intended behavior rather I think it is a result of the above markup being detached from the DOM and the reinserted...I could be wrong though.

Is there a way to make sure the loading graphic always appears in the exact center and there is no "animation"?

Here's a link to the script: https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll/blob/master/jquery.infinitescroll.js

I don't see any sort of CSS or JS creating this effect.

Comment: perhaps there is a transition css property in effect?

Comment: @RickCigarette I don't see anything of the sort. I updated the question above to include a link to the entire script.

Comment: @RickCigarette I was able to come across this on GitHub, any idea how I could send a loading.start function to remove the hickup...?

Answer (score 2):

I have centered the loading image by CSS:

```
#infscr-loading{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    text-align:center;
}
#infscr-loading div{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:360px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove it

```js
('#infscr-loading').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

*This has been tested with infinite-scroll v2.1.0.*

**Centering the loading indicator**

In your CSS, style `#infscr-loading` as you wish. To center the animation and the text:

```
#infscr-loading {
    text-align: center;
}
```

You can also define a completely custom loading indicator (the id `infscr-loading` is not required:

```
$('#content').infinitescroll({
    loading: {
        msg: $('<div style="text-align: center">Loading…</div>')
    }
});
```

**Disabling the animation**

```
$('#content').infinitescroll({
    loading: {
        speed: 0 // default: 'fast'
    }
});
```